# Ploting a Piecewise function obtained from linear interpolation of points

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I have no complains until `Plot`. `g[x]` seems good but `Plot` displays nothing. I need help. By advance Thanks

```
x[1] := 1; y[1] := 2;
x[2] := 2; y[2] := 3;
x[3] := 3; y[3] := 4;
x[4] := 4; y[4] := 1;
a = {x[1], y[1]};
b = {x[2], y[2]};
c = {x[3], y[3]};
d = {x[4], y[4]};
g[x_] := Piecewise[{
   {Interpolation[{a, b}, InterpolationOrder -> 1], {a[[1]] <= x < b[[1]]}}, 
   {Interpolation[{b, c}, InterpolationOrder -> 1], {b[[1]] <= x < c[[1]]}}, 
   {Interpolation[{c, d}, InterpolationOrder -> 1], {c[[1]] <= x < d[[1]]}}}]
g[x]
Plot[g[x], {x, 1, 4}]
```

Comment: Does `g[x_] := Piecewise[{{Interpolation[{a, b}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][
     x], a[[1]] <= x < 
     b[[1]]}, {Interpolation[{b, c}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], 
    b[[1]] <= x < 
     c[[1]]}, {Interpolation[{c, d}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x], 
    c[[1]] <= x < d[[1]]}}]` work?

Comment: Look at `g[1]` - as you can see, this is not correct

Comment: Why wouldn't you use `g = Interpolation[{a,b,c,d}, InterpolationOrder->1]` instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{Interpolation[{a, b}, InterpolationOrder->1]@x, a[[1]]<= x <b[[1]]},
  {Interpolation[{b, c}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]@x, b[[1]] <= x < c[[1]]},
  {Interpolation[{c, d}, InterpolationOrder -> 1]@x, c[[1]] <= x < d[[1]]}}]
g[x]
```

[image]

```
Plot[Evaluate@g[x], {x, 1, 4}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the @X