# Increasing readability of piecewise interpolate function

Tags: function-construction, piecewise

This is a follow-up question to [Ploting a Piecewise function obtained from linear interpolation of points](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/175074/ploting-a-piecewise-function-obtained-from-linear-interpolation-of-points/175075#175075), where I asked how to construct a piecewise function from a list of points.

I now have two following questions :

1) Is it possible to display the linear interpolation with linear functions  $f_i(x) = a x + b$ ?

2) Is it possible  to make `h[x_] = Composition[g, g][x]` more readable if `g` obtained from the previous question --- obviously the plot of `h[x]` is correct ?

Comment: See [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html)(see also last example in [`InterpolatingFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html)) and [`PiecewiseExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PiecewiseExpand.html)

Answer (score 2):

Referring to your previous question: Why do you need the Piecewise construction. Pack it in one InterpolationFunction.

```
x[1] := 1; y[1] := 2;
x[2] := 2; y[2] := 3;
x[3] := 3; y[3] := 4;
x[4] := 4; y[4] := 1;
a = {x[1], y[1]};
b = {x[2], y[2]};
c = {x[3], y[3]};
d = {x[4], y[4]};

g[x_ /; 1 <= x <= 4] = Interpolation[{a, b, c, d}, InterpolationOrder -> 1][x]

h = Composition[g, g]

(*  Composition[InterpolatingFunction [{{1,4}},"<>"],
                InterpolatingFunction [{{1,4}},"<>"]]  *)

{Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 5}], Plot[h[x], {x, 0, 5}]}
```

[image]

**Edit**

Get functions

```
pts = {a, b, c, d}

tp = Transpose[{Rest[pts], Drop[pts, -1]}]

(*   {{{2, 3}, {1, 2}}, {{3, 4}, {2, 3}}, {{4, 1}, {3, 4}}}   *)

ip = InterpolatingPolynomial[#, x] & /@ tp

(*   {1 + x, 1 + x, 1 - 3 (-4 + x)}   *)

Show[Plot[g[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}], 
     Plot[ip, {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Thin, Thin, Thin}], 
        PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]